Docker stack deploy postgres container but getting - did not find expected key - when using secrets and command for ssl=on
I have two docker-compose.yml files and one works but the other with 'command' that supplies ssl=on does not.
docker-compose.yml - without commaond ssl - works

services:
  postgres-example-pg-hba:
    image: mybuild:1
    secrets: 
      - pg_password
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_USER_FILE=mysuperuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/pg_password
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
          - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

secrets:
  pg_password:
    external: true


docker-compose.yml - with command ssl=on - causes error

services:
  postgres-example-pg-hba:
    image: mybuild:1
    secrets: 
      - pg_password
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_USER=mysuperuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/pg_password
   command:
      -c ssl=on 
      -c ssl_cert_file=/temp/ssl/server.crt
      -c ssl_key_file=/temp/ssl/server.key
      -c ssl_ca_file=/temp/ssl/root.crt
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
          - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

secrets:
  pg_password:
    external: true


when I run the follwing commands:

docker build -t mybuild:1 .
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml secret_test

I get error:

yaml: line 10: did not find expected key


I have a workaround, by removing the commands from the docker-compose.yml and instead adding them to the Dockerfile:
Dockerfile
# ...otherstuff..
CMD ["-c","ssl=on", "-c","ssl_cert_file=/temp/ssl/server.crt","-c","ssl_key_file=/temp/ssl/server.key","-c","ssl_ca_file=/temp/ssl/root.crt"]

